# Confusing CO-RELATION IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

May anyone please help me with code for below situation.

Two tables `Driver` and `Product`

Product

```
DECLARE @PRODUCT TABLE
(
    [Base Part] VARCHAR (50),
    [REP PART] VARCHAR (50),
    [Base Line] VARCHAR (50),
    [REP LINE]  VARCHAR (50) 
)

INSERT @PRODUCT
SELECT 'EXT8765',       'EXT8765-35',       'Cold Air Intake',  'TNNEAUCVRL'        UNION ALL
SELECT 'EXT40655',      'EXT7205-1',        'Cold Air Intake',  'TONORLCRNR'        UNION ALL
SELECT 'AFE54-11602',   'AFE24-60505',      'Cold Air Intake',  'STEERING'          UNION ALL
SELECT 'UNDUC4070',     'UNDRSIH1212GS',    'Cold Air Intake',  'Air Filter Big'    UNION ALL
SELECT 'EXT44720',      'EXT43720B',        'Cold Air Intake',  'Air Filter Small'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'EXT50725',      'EXT50725',         'TONNEAUCOV',       'TNNEAUCVRL'        UNION ALL
SELECT 'KMWXD77',       'KMW10007',         'WHEEL',            'WHLCTRCAP'         UNION ALL
SELECT 'KCH1761',       'KCH3079',          'FGLGTKIT',         'FGLGHTLENS'        UNION ALL
SELECT 'EXT38650',      'EXT3865',          'TONNEAUCOV',       'TONNOBOW'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALS6097KL',     'ALS117',           'FUELFILLER',       'HONDACITY' 

SELECT * FROM @PRODUCT
```

Driver

```
DECLARE @DRIVER TABLE
(
    [Base Line]     VARCHAR (50),
    [REP LINE]  VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @DRIVER
SELECT 'Cold Air Intake',   'Air Filter%'

SELECT * FROM @DRIVER
```

Rules:

I want to check in `Product` table whenever `basePart` have `baseline` equal to `base line` available in driver table
then its `REP Part` should also have **different** `REPLine` that is other than line available in driver table

Records those are  meeting this criteria, should be in output:

```
Base Part   REP PART    Base Line       REP LINE
---------------------------------------------------
EXT8765     EXT8765-35  Cold Air Intake TNNEAUCVRL
EXT40655    EXT7205-1   Cold Air Intake TONORLCRNR
AFE54-11602 AFE24-60505 Cold Air Intake STEERING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Question & expected result was revised, answer now revised to match.

How about this:

```
select *
from product as p
where exists (
  select 1
  from driver as d
  where p.[base line] = d.[base line]
  and   p.[rep line] not like d.[rep line]
)
```

See it in a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5526f/7

I hope I understood the question correctly. In future, please try to format it better, and explain what it is trying to do, perhaps even create a fiddle yourself to save us time and help us understand.

Comment: Hi Turophile. I am soory, if my words are confusing, The Output rows
consists of only those records whose base line are matching for Base part, but line for  Rep Part
is not matching with the driver table. Please Suggest

Comment: That's just a typo. Change `like` to `not like`.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, i have changed my expected Output. Please help

Comment: So you changed your request to only show records where the base line exists in driver. So simply add an according EXISTS clause to Turophile's query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thanks for responding while I was unavailable. I revised the answer and the fiddle to match the changes to the question.